# Hadoop corrupt blocks

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using hadoop 0.20.append and hbase 0.90.0. I uploaded few data into Hbase and then killed HMaster and Namenode for an evaluation purpose. After this I added few more data to the Hbase and I could see them in the hbase shell.

Now when I started the Namenode, I am facing problems. The log says that the name node is in safe mode and I am not able to add or delete the contents as it is in Safemode.

Also when I just ran

```
./bin/hadoop fsck /
```

I get,

```
............Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    12034 B (Total open files size: 4762 B)
 Total dirs:    22
 Total files:   12 (Files currently being written: 3)
 Total blocks (validated):      12 (avg. block size 1002 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 3)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   12 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     3.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          3
 Number of racks:               1
```

The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY

But when I run `./bin/hadoop fsck / -openforwrite`

I get,

```
Total size:    16796 B
 Total dirs:    22
 Total files:   15
 Total blocks (validated):      15 (avg. block size 1119 B)
  ********************************
  CORRUPT FILES:        2
  ********************************
 Minimally replicated blocks:   13 (86.666664 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication:     2.6
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          3
 Number of racks:               1
```

The filesystem under path '/' is CORRUPT

along with the info of corrupt blocks.

Also tried using

```
./bin/hadoop fsck / -move
```

But even after that getting the same list of corrupt blocks. Any idea regarding how to tackle this and recover my contents?

Comment: did you leave safe mode using : `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Comment: yes. After giving that, If I put any data in Hadoop then I get Inconsistent state exception and I am not able to recover back my data

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. In my experience, they cannot be recovered. The process to create the files was interrupted, and left them unattended. You can see if you can read them by:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/file
hdfs dfs -get /path/to/file local_file
```

And it was safe to delete them, because the failed process is responsible to retry the creation of those files again later.
And they should be removed, because such inconsistency can cause future problems.

Answer (score -1):

as it suggest,-openforwrite means when the set of files were getting written,they were not closed.So if you can look into fsck details you would see those files which were still reported open by hdfs fsck.I have faced this issue and only solution is to delete the files which are showing open in fsck.Let me know for any further questions.